# Problema con count mysql

Tags: mysql, count

tengo una cuestion que segun yo si se debe hacer así, pero el resultado es fallido.

Me explico, tengo una consulta que es:

```
SELECT resena.pkresena  as PkResena , resena.resena, usuario.Username, resena.fechaComentario
FROM 
usuario,
resena,
megustaresena
WHERE 
usuario.PkUsuario = resena.FkUsuario
AND megustaresena.fkResena = resena.pkresena
AND resena.FKJuego = 2
```

y me arroja esto

```
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| PkResena | resena | Username    | fechaComentario     |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
|        3 | Hola   | Jonciverka1 | 2020-07-26 17:05:24 |
|        3 | Hola   | Jonciverka1 | 2020-07-26 17:05:24 |
|        4 | adiós  | Jonciverka3 | 2020-07-26 17:09:33 |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
```

y quiero contar cuantas veces se repite el pkResena por ejemplo esto

```
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| Total    | resena | Username    | fechaComentario     |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
|        2 | Hola   | Jonciverka1 | 2020-07-26 17:05:24 |
|        1 | adiós  | Jonciverka3 | 2020-07-26 17:09:33 |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
```

he intentado esto  un count

```
SELECT count(resena.pkresena)  as PkResena , resena.resena, usuario.Username,resena.fechaComentario
FROM 
 usuario,
 resena,
 megustaresena
WHERE 
 usuario.PkUsuario = resena.FkUsuario
 AND megustaresena.fkResena = resena.pkresena
 AND resena.FKJuego = 2
```

pero me arroja esto

```
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
| PkResena | resena | Username    | fechaComentario     |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
|        3 | Hola   | Jonciverka1 | 2020-07-26 17:05:24 |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+
```

e igual intente el con un left join

```
SELECT resena.pkresena  as PkResena , resena.resena, usuario.Username, resena.fechaComentario, count(megustaresena.pkmegustaResena)
FROM 
 usuario,
 resena
 left join megustaresena
 on megustaresena.fkResena = resena.pkresena
WHERE 
 usuario.PkUsuario = resena.FkUsuario
 AND resena.FKJuego = 2
```

pero me sale esto

```
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
| PkResena | resena | Username    | fechaComentario     | count(megustaresena.pkmegustaResena) |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
|        3 | Hola   | Jonciverka1 | 2020-07-26 17:05:24 |                                    3 |
+----------+--------+-------------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

así que me quede sin opciones alguien sabe por que me esta saliendo esos resultados? y como puedo llegar a lo que quiero

Comment: Por favor usa sintaxis moderna de JOINs, disponible desde SQL-92.

Comment: El cualquiera de tus selects que incluyen count te hace falta agrupar pues me parece por eso te reduce todo a una fila además de lo que te dicen arriba

Comment: Hay 2 cosas que hay que tomar en cuenta, la primera como te dicen es preferible utilizar `JOIN` al unir las tablas, la segunda es que es necesario agrupar cuando utilizas una función tipo `COUNT`, `SUM` o `AVG`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando necesitas agregar **algunas** columnas de un `SELECT`, debes usar `GROUP BY`. Probablemente estás usando una versión de MySQL anterior a 5.7.5 que acepta consultas SQL incompletas como la que muestras. Las versiones modernas de MySQL ya no aceptan consultas así (por defecto).

Al agregar el `GROUP BY` la consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT
  count(r.pkresena) as PkResena,
  r.resena, 
  u.Username,
  r.fechaComentario
FROM usuario u
JOIN resena r ON u.PkUsuario = r.FkUsuario
JOIN megustaresena m ON m.fkResena = r.pkresena
WHERE r.FKJuego = 2
GROUP BY r.resena, u.Username, r.fechaComentario
```

Aquí puedes ver que las columnas no *agregadas* están presentes en el `GROUP BY`.

Nota: aproveché de modernizar los joins, de acuerdo al estándar SQL-92.